# why is sessionId generated for create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, session-cookies, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server, httpcookie

I was inspecting cookies section under `Applications` tab of Chrome dev tools and I noticed that a sample app created with create-react-app stores a cookie with `name=SESSIONID` in browser
What could be the  reason for storing this cookie in browser?
[image]

Comment: That is a webpack dev server thing, not specific to react.

Comment: I have another project that is just using webpack-dev server, and there change is instead of `SESSIONID` it is `connect.sid` and instead of `date` for expires value is `Session` so feels like cra team has done some configuration as well